# Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes for Android AIR AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, scale, flash-cs6

Hey everyone so I created a game using Flash CS6 and Flash Develop AS3.

Now the stage Width is 480 and the height is 800 so 480 by 800.

Now on my phone it fits perfectly but on others it doesnt fill the whole screen at all. It just looks ugly. Now I looked through a lot of forums even questions on here but still can't seem to find an exact answer on how to go about doing this. I am just really confused.

I have these properties in my mainEngine Class:

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
```

and in my constructor:

```
        //Scale
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; 
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

This does nothing but make the screen look uglier and shrinks the whole screen.

Please if anyone can assist with what I need to add in order to support multiple screen sizes ill really appreciate it!

Comment: First, you don't set a stage size for mobile apps and you don't set the `stage.align` or `stage.scaleMode` properties, either. Everything is set up by default to fit the device. You just need to make your app's GUI flexible, rather than being designed to fit a single size. In all honesty, this is probably going to require quite a bit of work on your end. You'll probably have to rewrite the majority of your layout code.

Comment: Ahh. I was hoping that would not be the case. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 1):

Read here to learn basics how to work with multiple screens:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html

Comment: I've done this but Ugh still having trouble been doing this for awhile now and cant get it working. It just scales it completely off and on tablets it is a MESS!